# how to detect page scroll to bottom in a nextjs application

Tags: next.js, scroll

I just need to have a window scroll position detector, I've tried code from multiple articles that I've found and none of them seem to work. Most of the times the console.logs will appear only when I refresh the page, but never get updated when user is actually scroling.

I need this to add infinite loading on a marketplace, and I'm not going to use any complex 3rd party libraries or something to do something so trivial.

Here is the current code I'm using, although it doesn't work at all (note that I've tried multiple different iterations of this code from all accross the web and none work)

```
const handleScroll = () => {
  console.log("scroll")
};

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This just uses react state and you can use it as a hook in any component. All you have to do is set a useEffect to trigger everytime it changes and it will trigger whenever it reaches the threshold you set.

Here is the hook

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function useScrollPosition() {
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);

  function handleScroll() {
    const height =
      document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
      document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    const windowScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    const scrolled = (windowScroll / height) * 100;

    setScrollPosition(scrolled);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  });

  return scrollPosition;
}
```

And how to use it in a component

```
function Component() {
  const scrollPosition = useScrollPosition();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollPosition > 80) {
      // something happens after it reaches 80% of the screen
    }
    }, [scrollPosition]);

  return (
    <div>{scrollPosition}</div>
}
```

Comment: Sadly as everything else this only works the first time when page loads, when I'm scrolling nothing hapens.

Comment: I would check if the way you are querying your data is correct. What library are you using for an infinite query? If you get data on the page load but not on scroll then maybe you are calling your infinite query incorrectly.

Comment: I'ts not as much as me getting data, it's that the handleScroll() function is not even being fired when I'm scrolling. It only fires the first time when page loads.